# show categories and subcategories hierarchically custom post

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I use this code for get all categories and subcategories, this work but not show subcategories hierarchically.

```
$args = array(
                'hide_empty'    => 1,
                'hierarchical'  => 1,
                'pad_counts'    => false
            );

$categories = get_terms('project_category', $args); 
echo '<ul>';
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                echo '<li class="s"></li><li><a href="#'. $category->slug .'" data-filter=".category-'. $category->slug .'">'. $category->name .'</a> B</li>';
            }
echo '</ul>';
```

I can't use wp_list_categories() because don´t show ul tag and adds some other div

as I can distinguish between categories and subcategories unused wp_list_categories()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Use this way for display categories and subcategories

```
<?php

$parent_cat_arg = array('hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0 );
$parent_cat = get_terms('category',$parent_cat_arg);//category name

foreach ($parent_cat as $catVal) {

    echo '<h2>'.$catVal->name.'</h2>'; //Parent Category

    $child_arg = array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $catVal->term_id );
    $child_cat = get_terms( 'category', $child_arg );

    echo '<ul>';
        foreach( $child_cat as $child_term ) {
            echo '<li>'.$child_term->name . '</li>'; //Child Category
        }
    echo '</ul>';

}
?>
```

Output
[image]